# Folder containing subfolders, that contain multiple files (.xlsm, .pdf, .txt). How to rename .pdf files to subfolders' name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This could be done with python, but I think I am missing a way to loop for all directories. Here is the code I am using:

```
import os
 def renameInDir(directory):  
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
      if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        path = os.path.realpath(filename)
        parents = path.split('/') //make an array of all the dirs in the path. 0 will be the original basefilename
        newFilename=os.path.dirname(filename)+directory +parents[-1:][0] //reorganize data into format you want 
        os.rename(filename, newFilename)//rename the file
```

Comment: I didn't get how the new file names should be. Are you wondering to just remove the PDF extension, or are you trying to replace it?

Comment: Could you pls inform if the solution below worked for you? If so, could you pls accept the answer? @Eduardo Valdez

Answer (score 0):

You should go with [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). It will map the directory tree by the given directory param, and generate the file names.

Using [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) you'll accomplish the desired result is this way:

```
import os
from os.path import join
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/path/to/directory'):
    for name in filenames:
        new_name = name[:-3] + 'new_file_extension'
        os.rename(join(dirpath, name), join(dirpath, new_name))
```